# How do I insert collection of objects using MyBatis 3.x?

Tags: collections, insert, orm, ibatis, mybatis

I'm a beginner with MyBatis.

I just want to know how to insert a collection of objects from an instance of a class. Say I have a class User related to a Note in one-to-many relationship. I just like to mention that I built my schema using JPA 2 annotations via Hibernate's hbm2ddl. I'll add the key JPA annotations I used in the sample code below.

Here's a sample:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    ...
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="user")
    public List<Note> getNotes() {...}
    ...
}
```

Now, everytime I insert something into User table I have to insert instances into the Note table if the list is not empty. Take note of the @JoinColumn in Note table which should have the id of the inserted User, which I have set to be autogenerated.

Has anyone got something like this working? Thanks.

Comment: Check detail Answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486547/mybatis-batch-insert-update-for-oracle?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using a regular MyBatis XML mapping config you can use something like this:

Java classes:

```
class EnclosingType {
  private List<ElementType> elements;
}

class ElementType {
  String a;
  String b;
  (...)
}
```

Mapper xml:

```
<mapper
    namespace="my.example.ElementType">
    <insert id="insertElements" parameterType="EnlosingType">
        INSERT INTO ELEMENTTYPE (enclosingTypeId, column_a, column_b)
        VALUES
        <foreach item="element" index="index" collection="elements"
            open="(" separator="),(" close=")">
            #{id}, #{element.a}, #{element.b}
        </foreach>
    </insert>
</mapper>
```

Comment: is there a way to do this Using annotations?

Comment: As I understand it this would be one of those things annotations can't do

Comment: Whoa.. Your solution saved my day, thanks! I was using just simple "," as separator. Thanks!

Comment: check detail answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486547/mybatis-batch-insert-update-for-oracle?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Remeber Insert all is treated as one transaction and if you are using sequence in any column, this will not work