# MySQL: How to Update values into multiple rows and use where clause as well?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to **Update** an int value (the value of a `primary key`, *retrieved from another table named `country`*) into the `city_id` column (which is a `Foreign Key` in the `persons` table from the `country` table), **in all the rows** where the value of the `name` attribute/column is `John, Amy, Adam, Abraham, Bob, David, Robert, George, Elizabeth, Mike and Barbara.`

I tried using this query but I get **an exception that there is an error in my MySQL syntax**.

```
String query1="update persons set city_id="+rid+" where "
                + "(name= 'John' and "
                + "name= 'Amy' and "
                + "name= 'Adam' and "
                + "name= 'Abraham' and "
                + "name= 'Bob' and "
                + "name= 'David' and "
                + "name= 'Robert' and "
                + "name= 'George' and "
                + "name= 'Elizabeth' and "
                + "name= 'Mike' and "
                + "name= 'Barbara' )";
```

I tried this by removing the parenthesis as well.

**So can somebody point out what's wrong with it, or another query which can serve my purpose?**

Comment: why you use AND.? use IN operator instead

Comment: put your sample data here if possible.

Comment: This is some sample data. You can see the names, the table names and the important key names are mentioned as well. One thing to mention is that the `country` table's `city_id` column (which is the `foreign key` in the `persons` table) has only one value (because there is only one `row` in the table)

Comment: Hi you  need to use batch for multiple  update or insert query ... I   done this using java and mybatis framework

Comment: for update multiple  columns with different where close refer my answer on this question

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928799/how-to-implement-batch-operations-with-mybatis-spring/18634322#18634322

Answer (score 1):

you could use

```
String query1="update persons set city_id="+rid+" where 
name= 'John' or 
name= 'Amy' or 
name= 'Adam' or 
name= 'Abraham' or 
name= 'Bob' or 
name= 'David' or 
name= 'Robert' or 
name= 'George' or 
name= 'Elizabeth' or 
name= 'Mike' or 
name= 'Barbara'";
```

or you could use

```
String query1="update persons set city_id="+rid+" where name in ('John','Amy','Adam','Abraham','Bob','David','Robert','George','Elizabeth','Mike','Barbara')";
```

Comment: I just used the second one. It removes the error but adds the value in only one last row in the city_id column in persons :s

Answer (score -1):

you should use the following command,and it definitely works

update persons set city_id="+rid+" where 
                name= 'John' 
                OR name='Amy' 
                OR name='Adam' 
                OR  name='Abraham' 
                OR name= 'Bob' 
                OR  name='David' 
                OR  name='Robert' 
                OR  name='George'
 OR name='Elizabeth' 
OR name='Mike'
                OR name='Barbara';

Comment: how it will definitely works? there is syntax error in the query. you can not write OR condition like this without bracket.

Comment: yes,we can write an OR condition without using a bracket...im trying to upload the pic in which I executed the command without using the bracket...but I don't have enough reputation to upload a pic

Comment: make sql fiddle for that and share link over here.

Comment: It definitely does not work; that is invalid SQL.  You would need something along the lines of `where name= 'John' OR name='Amy' ...`

Comment: @cr7 - and you'll notice that ID 2 doesn't get updated (actually, ID 3 doesn't get updated either, but since its ID is already 3, you can't tell).  Try adding a fourth or fifth row and use the method you suggest, and you'll notice they *also* won't update.

Comment: @Littlebobbytables.. yeah.they r not getting updated...thanks a lot