# Java Mybatis multiple update statements

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis

Java Mybatis Oracle

I have following mybatis statement in xml file

```
<update id="updateOfferIndex" parameterType="java.util.List">
   <foreach collection="list" item="offer"  index="index"  separator=";" >
        UPDATE  offer set indx=#{offer.idx} WHERE id=#{offer.eId}
    </foreach>
```

I am getting following error, can any one help ?

```
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character

### The error may involve com.dao.linear.upsell.LinearUpsellDao.updateOfferIndex-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: UPDATE  offer set indx=? WHERE id=?   ;       UPDATE  offer set indx=? WHERE id=?
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

Comment: how does this call looks like in java? I thought it is not possible to call multiple statements with one execute.

Comment: upsellDao.updateOfferIndex(offers);

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928799/how-to-implement-batch-operations-with-mybatis-spring

Answer (score 4):

I resolve by insert BEGIN-END statements in this way:

```
BEGIN
<foreach collection="list" item="offer"  index="index"  separator=";" >
        UPDATE  offer set indx=#{offer.idx} WHERE id=#{offer.eId}
</foreach>;
END;
```

I hope this resolves.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the last semicolon has not been appended:

```
    ### SQL: UPDATE  offer set indx=? WHERE id=?;       
    UPDATE  offer set indx=? WHERE id=?;
```

And this is coherent with the mybatis [documentation](http://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html) about the foreach's separator:

> The element is smart in that it won’t accidentally append extra
>   separators.

Try adding a semicolon to the XML mapping:

```
  <foreach collection="list" item="offer"  index="index"  separator=";" >
        UPDATE  offer set indx=#{offer.idx} WHERE id=#{offer.eId}
  </foreach>
  ;
```