# SqlMapClientCallback alternative in Mybatis-spring

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis

I am refactoring/migrating the system from java 6 to java 8 and consequently, I need to migrate from ibatis to mybatis-spring as well. I am new to both ibatis and mybatis, therefore I stumble into problems once in a while.

The system is full of code like this

```
sqlMapTemplate.execute(new SqlMapClientCallback()
    { public Object doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapExecutor executor)  
      ... 
    }
```

The question is - what is the alternative to ibatis SqlMapClientCallback in mybatis to do batch operations and how it should be done?

Comment: Take a look at [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928799/how-to-implement-batch-operations-with-mybatis-spring).