# mybatis oracle batch update using foreach

Tags: oracle11g, mybatis

I'm trying to insert a list of records to an Oracle 11g  table. I tried the MyBatis syntax with foreach but it fails with ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended exception when the list has more than one record.

```
The generated sql in this case looks like:
```

UPDATE CUSTOMER_T SET app_name = ?, start_date = ?, end_date = ? WHERE customer_id=?
UPDATE CUSTOMER_T SET app_name = ?, start_date = ?, end_date = ? WHERE customer_id=?

```
Below is my the query in the mapper:

<update id="updateApplication" parameterType="com.test.mybatis.Application">

        <foreach item="ca" collection="customer.applications.applcation"
            open="" close="" separator="">
        UPDATE CUSTOMER_T
        SET app_name = #{ca.appName,jdbcType=VARCHAR},      
        start_date = #{ca.startDate,jdbcType=DATE,javaType=javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar},
        end_date = #{ca.endDate,jdbcType=DATE,javaType=javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar}
        WHERE
        customer_id=#{customer.info.customerid}
        </foreach>      
    </update>
```

I appreciate if someone could identify the issue here.

Comment: In the `separator` attribute, try putting in `;` and seeing if it works.

Comment: Already tried that .. it doesn't work.

Comment: Is `customer.applications.application` the collection?  Or is `customer.applications` the actual collection?

Comment: customer.applications.application is the collection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MyBatis Batch Insert/Update For Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486547/mybatis-batch-insert-update-for-oracle)