# MyBatis batch update for oracle

Tags: mybatis, batch-updates

I am trying to do the batch update in myBatis with oracle Database, where i have to update 10K+ records.
But when i use below

I am getting exception says 'invalid character'.
It is working fine when i do single update statement multiple times.
Please help with your example if you already tried this.

```
<update id="batchUpdate">
                <foreach collection="empList" item="employee" separator=";">
                  UPDATE Employee
                   SET  EMP_JOBTITLE = #{employee.jobTitle},
                        EMP_STATUS = #{employee.status}
                        WHERE Employee_ID = #{employee.empId}
                  </foreach>
    </update>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MyBatis Batch Insert/Update For Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486547/mybatis-batch-insert-update-for-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Oracle:

```
<update id="batchUpdate">
call 
begin
<foreach collection="empList" item="employee" close=";" eparator=";">
                  UPDATE Employee
                   SET  EMP_JOBTITLE = #{employee.jobTitle},
                        EMP_STATUS = #{employee.status}
                        WHERE Employee_ID = #{employee.empId}
</foreach>
end
</update>
```

Comment: This gives me ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name

Answer (score -1):

I was not able to resolve that error, but came across this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mybatis-user/oracle$20batch$20update/mybatis-user/8QxLH7XuYlU/mLT5WT_TokoJ) in which a code contributor recommended that the proper way to batch update is to open a session in batch mode and repeatedly call update for a single record.

Here's what works for me:

```
public void updateRecords(final List<GisObject> objectsToUpdate) {
    final SqlSession sqlSession = MyBatisUtils.getSqlSessionFactory().openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH);
    try {
        final GisObjectMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(GisObjectMapper.class);
        for (final GisObject gisObject : objectsToUpdate) {
            mapper.updateRecord(gisObject);
        }
        sqlSession.commit();
    } finally {
        sqlSession.close();
    }
}
```

Then, remove the foreach in your update and modify it to update a single record (remove the "employee.")