# Fastest way to update huge number of rows with input param List<T> in MyBatis to Oracle db

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, sql-update, mybatis

I'm updating huge amount of data by passing a variable List in MyBatis to Oracle DB.

Methods from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23486547/mybatis-batch-insert-update-for-oracle)  are not efficient enough for me, the ways to commit update sql query line by line, for loop in sql query or Executor.batch service are way too slow from what I expect.

```
//one of the method i use
<update id="updateAll">
    BEGIN
        <foreach collection="list" item="item" index="index" separator=";">
            UPDATE <include refid="tableName"/>
            <set>
                item_price = ${item.price}, update_time = ${item.updateTime}
            </set>
            WHERE id = ${item.id}
        </foreach>
    ;END;
</update>
```

With the ways I tried, my system spend 10 - 30 seconds or maybe longer to complete the update. There will be around 10,000 rows of data per sec from server. Is there is any way to update at least 1-2k rows of data within 1 or 2 second in Oracle db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using batch executor is the recommended way, but you need to do it properly.
Two issues that I noticed.

1. Setting a proper batch size is important. The [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29264696/1261766) sends all the data at the end which is not efficient very much.
2. Using `${}` to reference parameters makes each statement unique and prevents the driver from reusing the statement (the benefit of batch executor is lost, basically). See [this FAQ](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-) for the difference between `#{}` and `${}`.

Here is a typical batch operation using MyBatis.
As the best `batchSize` depends on various factors, you should measure the performance using the actual data.

```java
int batchSize = 1000;
try (SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH)) {
  YourMapper mapper = sqlSession.getMapper(YourMapper.class);
  int size = list.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < size;) {
    mapper.update(list.get(i));
    i++;
    if (i % batchSize == 0 || i == size) {
      sqlSession.flushStatements();
      sqlSession.clearCache();
    }
  }
  sqlSession.commit();
}
```

And here is an efficient version of the update statement.

```xml
<update id="update">
  UPDATE <include refid="tableName" />
  SET
    item_price = #{item.price},
    update_time = #{item.updateTime}
  WHERE id = #{item.id}
</update>
```

Comment: arhhhh, I've spent a whole day on this just bcuz of a symbol.. For inserting it works fine!!! but somehow it hang and not throwing error at sql.flushstatement() while using update query.. Thanks anyway!!

Comment: A symbol can ruin our day sometimes :D Regarding the update issue, there may be row(s) that are locked by another thread.

Comment: hey in my case, sqlSession.flushStatements() [end of the loop] is committing the changes to database before the .commit() statement..? do you know why and how we can avoid this? FYI, I am using/declaring the session as openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH, false)