# Unable to insert the batch in sql via MyBatis

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-sql

I've recently started learning to use MyBatis and I am stuck up in one scenario. I am not able to insert the list of Reason object in sql by using MyBatis. I am having below ReasonMapper.xml file but not able to understand how to write insert query to insert reason object as a batch.

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="aero.sita.gsl.ee.services.referencedata.generated.mapper.ReasonMapper">
  <resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="aero.sita.gsl.ee.services.referencedata.generated.model.Reason">
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbg.generated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Sun Apr 05 18:38:46 IST 2020.
    -->
    <result column="REASON_ID" jdbcType="CHAR" property="reasonId" />
    <result column="IS_NOTE_REQUIRED" jdbcType="BIT" property="isNoteRequired" />
    <result column="IS_SYSTEM_RESERVED" jdbcType="BIT" property="isSystemReserved" />
    <result column="EFFECTIVE_FROM" jdbcType="NVARCHAR" property="effectiveFrom" />
    <result column="EFFECTIVE_TO" jdbcType="NVARCHAR" property="effectiveTo" />
    <result column="CREATED_ON" jdbcType="TIMESTAMP" property="createdOn" />
    <result column="CREATED_BY" jdbcType="NVARCHAR" property="createdBy" />
    <result column="LAST_UPDATED_ON" jdbcType="TIMESTAMP" property="lastUpdatedOn" />
    <result column="LAST_UPDATED_BY" jdbcType="NVARCHAR" property="lastUpdatedBy" />
    <result column="REASON_TYPE" jdbcType="NVARCHAR" property="reasonType" />
    <result column="REASON_NAME" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="reasonName" />
  </resultMap>
  <sql id="Example_Where_Clause">
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbg.generated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Sun Apr 05 18:38:46 IST 2020.
    -->
    <where>
      <foreach collection="oredCriteria" item="criteria" separator="or">
        <if test="criteria.valid">
          <trim prefix="(" prefixOverrides="and" suffix=")">
            <foreach collection="criteria.criteria" item="criterion">
              <choose>
                <when test="criterion.noValue">
                  and ${criterion.condition}
                </when>
                <when test="criterion.singleValue">
                  and ${criterion.condition} #{criterion.value}
                </when>
                <when test="criterion.betweenValue">
                  and ${criterion.condition} #{criterion.value} and #{criterion.secondValue}
                </when>
                <when test="criterion.listValue">
                  and ${criterion.condition}
                  <foreach close=")" collection="criterion.value" item="listItem" open="(" separator=",">
                    #{listItem}
                  </foreach>
                </when>
              </choose>
            </foreach>
          </trim>
        </if>
      </foreach>
    </where>
  </sql>
  <sql id="Update_By_Example_Where_Clause">
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbg.generated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Sun Apr 05 18:38:46 IST 2020.
    -->
    <where>
      <foreach collection="example.oredCriteria" item="criteria" separator="or">
        <if test="criteria.valid">
          <trim prefix="(" prefixOverrides="and" suffix=")">
            <foreach collection="criteria.criteria" item="criterion">
              <choose>
                <when test="criterion.noValue">
                  and ${criterion.condition}
                </when>
                <when test="criterion.singleValue">
                  and ${criterion.condition} #{criterion.value}
                </when>
                <when test="criterion.betweenValue">
                  and ${criterion.condition} #{criterion.value} and #{criterion.secondValue}
                </when>
                <when test="criterion.listValue">
                  and ${criterion.condition}
                  <foreach close=")" collection="criterion.value" item="listItem" open="(" separator=",">
                    #{listItem}
                  </foreach>
                </when>
              </choose>
            </foreach>
          </trim>
        </if>
      </foreach>
    </where>
  </sql>
  <sql id="Base_Column_List">
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbg.generated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Sun Apr 05 18:38:46 IST 2020.
    -->
    REASON_ID, IS_NOTE_REQUIRED, IS_SYSTEM_RESERVED, EFFECTIVE_FROM, EFFECTIVE_TO, CREATED_ON, 
    CREATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_ON, LAST_UPDATED_BY, REASON_TYPE, REASON_NAME
  </sql>
  <select id="selectByExample" parameterType="aero.sita.gsl.ee.services.referencedata.generated.model.ReasonExample" resultMap="BaseResultMap">
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbg.generated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Sun Apr 05 18:38:46 IST 2020.
    -->
    select
    <if test="distinct">
      distinct
    </if>
    <include refid="Base_Column_List" />
    from REASON
    <if test="_parameter != null">
      <include refid="Example_Where_Clause" />
    </if>
    <if test="orderByClause != null">
      order by ${orderByClause}
    </if>
  </select>
  <delete id="deleteByExample" parameterType="aero.sita.gsl.ee.services.referencedata.generated.model.ReasonExample">
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbg.generated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Sun Apr 05 18:38:46 IST 2020.
    -->
    delete from REASON
    <if test="_parameter != null">
      <include refid="Example_Where_Clause" />
    </if>
  </delete>
  <insert id="insert" parameterType="aero.sita.gsl.ee.services.referencedata.generated.model.Reason">
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbg.generated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Sun Apr 05 18:38:46 IST 2020.
    -->
    insert into REASON (REASON_ID, IS_NOTE_REQUIRED, IS_SYSTEM_RESERVED, 
      EFFECTIVE_FROM, EFFECTIVE_TO, CREATED_ON, 
      CREATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_ON, LAST_UPDATED_BY, 
      REASON_TYPE, REASON_NAME)
    values (#{reasonId,jdbcType=CHAR}, #{isNoteRequired,jdbcType=BIT}, #{isSystemReserved,jdbcType=BIT}, 
      #{effectiveFrom,jdbcType=NVARCHAR}, #{effectiveTo,jdbcType=NVARCHAR}, #{createdOn,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP}, 
      #{createdBy,jdbcType=NVARCHAR}, #{lastUpdatedOn,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP}, #{lastUpdatedBy,jdbcType=NVARCHAR}, 
      #{reasonType,jdbcType=NVARCHAR}, #{reasonName,jdbcType=VARCHAR})
  </insert>
  <insert id="insertSelective" parameterType="aero.sita.gsl.ee.services.referencedata.generated.model.Reason">
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbg.generated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Sun Apr 05 18:38:46 IST 2020.
    -->
    insert into REASON
    <trim prefix="(" suffix=")" suffixOverrides=",">
      <if test="reasonId != null">
        REASON_ID,
      </if>
      <if test="isNoteRequired != null">
        IS_NOTE_REQUIRED,
      </if>
      <if test="isSystemReserved != null">
        IS_SYSTEM_RESERVED,
      </if>
      <if test="effectiveFrom != null">
        EFFECTIVE_FROM,
      </if>
      <if test="effectiveTo != null">
        EFFECTIVE_TO,
      </if>
      <if test="createdOn != null">
        CREATED_ON,
      </if>
      <if test="createdBy != null">
        CREATED_BY,
      </if>
      <if test="lastUpdatedOn != null">
        LAST_UPDATED_ON,
      </if>
      <if test="lastUpdatedBy != null">
        LAST_UPDATED_BY,
      </if>
      <if test="reasonType != null">
        REASON_TYPE,
      </if>
      <if test="reasonName != null">
        REASON_NAME,
      </if>
    </trim>
    <trim prefix="values (" suffix=")" suffixOverrides=",">
      <if test="reasonId != null">
        #{reasonId,jdbcType=CHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="isNoteRequired != null">
        #{isNoteRequired,jdbcType=BIT},
      </if>
      <if test="isSystemReserved != null">
        #{isSystemReserved,jdbcType=BIT},
      </if>
      <if test="effectiveFrom != null">
        #{effectiveFrom,jdbcType=NVARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="effectiveTo != null">
        #{effectiveTo,jdbcType=NVARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="createdOn != null">
        #{createdOn,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP},
      </if>
      <if test="createdBy != null">
        #{createdBy,jdbcType=NVARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="lastUpdatedOn != null">
        #{lastUpdatedOn,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP},
      </if>
      <if test="lastUpdatedBy != null">
        #{lastUpdatedBy,jdbcType=NVARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="reasonType != null">
        #{reasonType,jdbcType=NVARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="reasonName != null">
        #{reasonName,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
    </trim>
  </insert>
  <select id="countByExample" parameterType="aero.sita.gsl.ee.services.referencedata.generated.model.ReasonExample" resultType="java.lang.Long">
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbg.generated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Sun Apr 05 18:38:46 IST 2020.
    -->
    select count(*) from REASON
    <if test="_parameter != null">
      <include refid="Example_Where_Clause" />
    </if>
  </select>
  <update id="updateByExampleSelective" parameterType="map">
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbg.generated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Sun Apr 05 18:38:46 IST 2020.
    -->
    update REASON
    <set>
      <if test="record.reasonId != null">
        REASON_ID = #{record.reasonId,jdbcType=CHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="record.isNoteRequired != null">
        IS_NOTE_REQUIRED = #{record.isNoteRequired,jdbcType=BIT},
      </if>
      <if test="record.isSystemReserved != null">
        IS_SYSTEM_RESERVED = #{record.isSystemReserved,jdbcType=BIT},
      </if>
      <if test="record.effectiveFrom != null">
        EFFECTIVE_FROM = #{record.effectiveFrom,jdbcType=NVARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="record.effectiveTo != null">
        EFFECTIVE_TO = #{record.effectiveTo,jdbcType=NVARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="record.createdOn != null">
        CREATED_ON = #{record.createdOn,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP},
      </if>
      <if test="record.createdBy != null">
        CREATED_BY = #{record.createdBy,jdbcType=NVARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="record.lastUpdatedOn != null">
        LAST_UPDATED_ON = #{record.lastUpdatedOn,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP},
      </if>
      <if test="record.lastUpdatedBy != null">
        LAST_UPDATED_BY = #{record.lastUpdatedBy,jdbcType=NVARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="record.reasonType != null">
        REASON_TYPE = #{record.reasonType,jdbcType=NVARCHAR},
      </if>
      <if test="record.reasonName != null">
        REASON_NAME = #{record.reasonName,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
      </if>
    </set>
    <if test="_parameter != null">
      <include refid="Update_By_Example_Where_Clause" />
    </if>
  </update>
  <update id="updateByExample" parameterType="map">
    <!--
      WARNING - @mbg.generated
      This element is automatically generated by MyBatis Generator, do not modify.
      This element was generated on Sun Apr 05 18:38:46 IST 2020.
    -->
    update REASON
    set REASON_ID = #{record.reasonId,jdbcType=CHAR},
      IS_NOTE_REQUIRED = #{record.isNoteRequired,jdbcType=BIT},
      IS_SYSTEM_RESERVED = #{record.isSystemReserved,jdbcType=BIT},
      EFFECTIVE_FROM = #{record.effectiveFrom,jdbcType=NVARCHAR},
      EFFECTIVE_TO = #{record.effectiveTo,jdbcType=NVARCHAR},
      CREATED_ON = #{record.createdOn,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP},
      CREATED_BY = #{record.createdBy,jdbcType=NVARCHAR},
      LAST_UPDATED_ON = #{record.lastUpdatedOn,jdbcType=TIMESTAMP},
      LAST_UPDATED_BY = #{record.lastUpdatedBy,jdbcType=NVARCHAR},
      REASON_TYPE = #{record.reasonType,jdbcType=NVARCHAR},
      REASON_NAME = #{record.reasonName,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
    <if test="_parameter != null">
      <include refid="Update_By_Example_Where_Clause" />
    </if>
  </update>
</mapper>
```

I am having below methods in my ReasonMapper.java class :

```
package aero.sita.gsl.ee.services.referencedata.generated.mapper;

import aero.sita.gsl.ee.services.referencedata.generated.model.Reason;
import aero.sita.gsl.ee.services.referencedata.generated.model.ReasonExample;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;

public interface ReasonMapper {
    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table REASON
     *
     * @mbg.generated Sun Apr 05 18:38:46 IST 2020
     */
    long countByExample(ReasonExample example);

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table REASON
     *
     * @mbg.generated Sun Apr 05 18:38:46 IST 2020
     */
    int deleteByExample(ReasonExample example);

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table REASON
     *
     * @mbg.generated Sun Apr 05 18:38:46 IST 2020
     */
    int insert(Reason record);

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table REASON
     *
     * @mbg.generated Sun Apr 05 18:38:46 IST 2020
     */
    int insertSelective(Reason record);

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table REASON
     *
     * @mbg.generated Sun Apr 05 18:38:46 IST 2020
     */
    List<Reason> selectByExample(ReasonExample example);

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table REASON
     *
     * @mbg.generated Sun Apr 05 18:38:46 IST 2020
     */
    int updateByExampleSelective(@Param("record") Reason record, @Param("example") ReasonExample example);

    /**
     * This method was generated by MyBatis Generator.
     * This method corresponds to the database table REASON
     *
     * @mbg.generated Sun Apr 05 18:38:46 IST 2020
     */
    int updateByExample(@Param("record") Reason record, @Param("example") ReasonExample example);
}
```

I am looking for below method to insert the batch of reason object but now able to understand how to map it in the xml file.

```
int insertSelective(List<Reason> record);
```

I have done below changes in configuration file :

```
public class ReferenceDataConfiguration {

    /** The datasource url. */
    @Value("${gsl.ee.datasource.url}")
    private String datasourceUrl;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(datasourceUrl);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setTypeAliasesPackage("aero.sita.gsl.ee.services.referencedata");
        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public SqlSessionTemplate batchSqlSessionTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory(), ExecutorType.BATCH);
    }
```

And I am calling it on Dao class as below :

```
 for(Reason reasonInsert : reason){
      num = reasonMapper.insertSelective(reasonInsert);
  }
```

But above two changes are not doing any batch insertion.

Comment: Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56515063/) for how to perform batch operation using `ExecutorType.BATCH`. See the [doc](https://mybatis.org/spring/sqlsession.html) for how to prepare/use a batch `SqlSession` with MyBatis-Spring.

Comment: Thanks for the update @ave. I have a confusion like I need to update my ReasonMapper.xml file as well as the interface with the method and using that method on the Dao class ?

Comment: No need to change Java/XML mappers. Just change how to call the mapper method `ReasonMapper#insertSelective()`. You usually write the loop in service layer or in a DAO implementation class.

Comment: @ave: I have updated my code. can you please have a look ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not doing any batch insertion' ? The rows are not inserted at all? Maybe you should add 'expected result' and 'actual result' to the question.

Comment: @ave: I mean I have around 1200 rows and it is taking long time because while iterating the loop it is inserting the row one by one. I am looking to directly insert the List<Reason> object in one go.
I have 8 more objects apart from this Reason object to insert in the database.

Comment: If you expect it to generate SQL like `INSERT INTO table VALUES (...), (...), (...)`, it is not a batch operation (it's called multi-row insert) and is not efficient when there are many rows to insert. See this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/jdbc-batch-processing) for how JDBC batch works. If you want batch operation to be efficient, you should use `insert` instead of `insertSelective` because the latter could generated different `PreparedStatement`. Also, some DBs have options to improve batch performance, so you should add DB/driver versions to the question.

Comment: @ave So, it means there is no way to batch insert in MyBatis ?

Comment: The linked answer shows you how to execute batch insert using MyBatis. Maybe my explanation is bad. If someone has better explanation, please chime in. :D

Comment: @ave: Its my bad that I am not able to understand as I am new to MyBatis but I followed your link only and put code here as well according the same code but in your link also its not inserting as a batch.
It would be helpful if you can roughly made some dummy code from my given information for batch insertion. I will try that and update you regarding the same.

Comment: Did you understand my explanation about the difference between 'batch insert' and 'multi-row insert' ? I just wrote a [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-60993091) for another question which demonstrates a batch operation (one of the two tests performs batch insertion in the service class). It is based on MySQL, BTW. See if it matches your expectation.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.