# Why performance of splicing update sql is better than using batch executor?

Tags: jdbc, mybatis

The row of table is 20 millions, the row of waiting to update is 10k. Splicing update SQL like that `UPDATE xx SET a = x WHERE id = x;UPDATE xx SET a = x WHERE id = x;UPDATE xx SET a = x WHERE id = x;` (in one transactional) takes 700ms, but using batch executor of MyBatis takes 5300ms.

It's inconceivable, because the performance of splicing insert SQL like that `INSERT INTO XX(XX,XX) VALUES (XX,XX),(XX,XX),(XX,XX)` is lower than using batch executor.

I have set rewriteBatchedStatements=true and allowMultiQueries=true.

This is example of batch executor.

```java
    public void batchUpdate(List<People> peopleList) {
        SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH, false);
        PeopleMapper peopleMapper = sqlSession.getMapper(PeopleMapper.class);
        try {
            for (People people : peopleList) {
                peopleMapper.update(people);   
            }
            sqlSession.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            sqlSession.rollback();
        } finally {
            sqlSession.close();
        }
    }


    <update id="update" parameterType="com.lb.springboot.DO.People">
        update people set
          name = #{name},
          age = #{age},
          gmt_create = #{gmtCreate},
          gmt_modify = #{gmtModify},
          `type` = #{type},
          location = #{location},
          sex = #{sex},
          class = #{clazz},
          school = #{school},
          rand = #{rand}
        where id = #{id}
    </update>
```

This is example of Splicing update SQL.

```xml
    <update id="batchUpdate" parameterType="java.util.List">
        <foreach collection="peopleList" item="item" index="index" open="" close="" separator=";">
            update people
            <set>
                name = #{item.name},
                age = #{item.age},
                gmt_create = #{item.gmtCreate},
                gmt_modify = #{item.gmtModify},
                `type` = #{item.type},
                location = #{item.location},
                sex = #{item.sex},
                class = #{item.clazz},
                school = #{item.school},
                rand = #{item.rand}
            </set>
            where id = #{item.id}
        </foreach>
    </update>
```

The length of peopleList is 10k.

Comment: Did you disable auto-commit? Also, which database are you using? I'm guessing MySQL, but it's good to be explicit. Also, please post a [mre] that show exactly what you do.

Comment: @chen See the [FAQ entry](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-code-a-batch-insert) for how to use batch executor. JDBC batch operation is efficient when reusing the same `java.sql.PreparedStatement`, so concatenating multiple statements kills the benefit.

Comment: I have post my example, plz check.

Comment: @chen Controlling [batch size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56515063/1261766) might help, but I'm not sure. If it didn't help, try creating a small project that shows the difference as Mark suggested (you can share the project on your GitHub repo). Here are some project templates to start with: https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues